# Deploy printers to users (windows 7)

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am in a situation where we have a Windows domain controller (2008) with AD running on it. However there is little we can add on it, e.g. we cannot run it as a print server.

We currently run a print server on a Linux box. The printers can be added to windows pcs manually by adding the network printer and install the right driver.

Is there any way I can deploy the printers to users using GPO but the still use the linux print servers?

I'd think it is do-able by (1) installing drivers to the PCs, (2) deploying printers via GPO. Is this the right way to go?

Comment: If you setup Samba properly then your drivers can be stored on the Samba server and delivered when a user connects to that printer.  Fix your Linux box, and the Windows side should be trivial.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify - at the moment when a new PC is imaged, and the user logs on, there is no printer in the printer list, they have to manually add the printer(s). When you say fix my linux box, do you mean that the following can be achieved: when user logs in, the printers are all in the list with drivers having been 'delivered'?

Answer (score 0):

You can install drivers AND deploy printers all through GPO. If your print server is in a Linux box, you have to configure Samba to share the drivers.

See https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_as_a_print_server#Setting_up_a_GPO_for_trusting_printer_drivers